# How to update item from table1 to table2 in DynamoDb aws?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, bigdata

I want to update the records in table2 from table1

```
**Table1**   
City, Code   
Huntsville, AL  
**Table2**  
Location,State,Id  
Chicago,  Illinois,2222
```

I want to update data Table1.City items into Table2.Chicago.

```
AmazonDynamoDB dynamoclient= AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
                        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoclient);
 ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
        .withTableName("Table2")
        .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated);
scanRequest.
```

I just have gone thru basic scan after I didn't any idea how to update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would solve the problem.

Lambda -- Table1 (Update) -- DynamoDB Stream -- Lambda -- Table2 (Update)

Trying to do  within a single lambda is going to hurt the read and write capacity of those tables.

Comment: Thank you. Lambda is updating entire table but i need to update single item

Comment: Explain the problem clearly. What you want to do? You want to full scan on table1 and update a single record in table2 ?